# How sql query to join 2 table if we separated data from rows in same column on second table

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

i have trouble when i try to join my tables, because the data are from rows in same column on table. I've been trying all example code from stack, but can't solved the problem, here the explanation :

`tb_match`

```
  **liga**   |   **codehome**  | **codeaway**
  premiere   |        ap       |      be
```

`tb_team:`

```
  **code**   |   **team** 
     ap      |     alpha
     be      |     beta
```

I want to join that tables to be like this :

`joins:`

```
  **liga**   |   **codehome**  | **codeaway** | **home**  | **away**
  premiere   |      ap         |    be        |  alpha    |  betha
```

on tb_match we have only code team, and i want to change that codehome to home team name and codeaway to away team name.
thanks before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two joins:

```
select m.*, th.team as teamhome, ta.team as teamaway
from tb_match m left join
     tb_team th
     on m.codehome = th.code left join
     tb_team ta
     on m.codeaway = ta.code;
```